# node.js fs.writeFileSync() How to set encoding to big5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encode, fs, big5

the **fs.writeFileSync** encode default is **UTF 8**
I can't set the encode to big5.
The documentation does not mention those encoding support.
If this function does not support BIG5, what can I do?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var FilePath='./text.txt';
var Str='this is a test!';
var encode='utf8';
fs.writeFileSync(FilePath, Str, encode);
```

When I set encoding(var encode='big5';) BIG5, the server generates an error.

Comment: Use something like [`iconv-lite`](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use an encoding that isn't [standard with Node Core](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings). You can use [iconv-lite](https://npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite).

It adds support for additional encodings including `big5`, [here is the full list of encodings](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/wiki/Supported-Encodings).

```
const iconv = require('iconv-lite');
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');

var Str = iconv.encode('This is a test', 'big5');

var readStream = new stream.PassThrough();
var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./text.txt');

readStream.once('error', (err) => { console.log(err); });    
readStream.once('end', () => { console.log('File Written'); });

readStream.end(Str); // write data to stream    
readStream.pipe(writeStream); // pipe data to file
```

Comment: Just a nitpick, but would those two event handlers be better off above `readStream.end()`?

Comment: @Zlatko `readStream.end()` is just populating the stream with the data. I guess the `error` listener could be better before `readStream.end()` but the `end` event is only emitted when the stream has been drained fully, so that wouldn't *need* to be before `readStream.end()`. Moved both listeners before `end()` for neatness but only the `error` listener should be before it.

Comment: it's working! So amazing! Thank you for your answer! Why write this readStream.pipe(writeStream); in the last line?

Comment: @peteb Not sure about the details, would have to look into node sources. But the handlers, as far as I remember, get set on the next tick. And if `stream.end()` or an error come before the handlers get attached, we might miss those events and handlers are never fired. But like I've said, not sure as to when what does get scheduled exactly.

Comment: @Zlatko [the docs for the `'error'` event](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/stream.html#stream_event_error_1) makes it clear that  the `error` listener need to be before any other stream code since an error can occur at any time when using a `stream.Readable`. Since a `stream.PassThrough` implements both `stream.Readable` and `stream.Writable` we *need* to place the `error` listener before any stream interactions at a minimum. However, after further reflection, it makes most sense to place all listeners before any stream interactions to ensure all events are handled.

Comment: Yep, that's why I've said it in the first place - makes most sense. Glad you solved the OPs question in any case.

Comment: Now that I think of it, I'd place the pipe above the end, too :) same reason, you can't pipe a closed stream. In case that end was really fast. What do you think, @peteb?

Comment: @Zlatko From a logical standpoint, it makes sense to do the `end()` before the `pipe()` because the `readStream` is empty until that occurs. The `end()` is writing to the `Writable` interface and the `pipe()` is used by the `Readable` interface. So this this implementation is valid for a PassThrough/Duplex Stream.

Comment: But again I think it's about timings - if the stream has ended, you cannot pipe it elsewhere any more. Even logically I'd expect that, but you expect it differently, so let's put expectations aside and only talk impl. And I think streams work like that. If I had a computer on me I'd test it.

Comment: @Zlatko, I undestand where you're coming from but you're missing my point, the stream hasn't ended, not the readable portion, which is what uses `pipe()`. The `end()` is necessary before the `pipe()` because until the, the stream is empty and there is nothing to pipe. That is why this does work.